# Is there anyway to initiate chat in dialogflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am working in Dialogflow right now, is there any way to initiate chat using webhooks instead of using the common welcome massages given by dialogflow or some chat apps. Like I want to have my own initialize chats for many different situations. For example, today is my day to save money, then it will initiate a chat to make sure user get into save_money_daily intent. More details on the comment

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It isn't clear exactly what your question is or what problem you're having. You may want to provide as many details as you can about how you're using Dialogflow. For example, are you trying to do this with your own website, or with a particular chat client? Have you tried anything that isn't working? The more info you can provide, the better our chances are of helping you.

Comment: Hi, so I am working for an android app that has a chat feature. This app will remind you some sort of things such as to save your money today. So there are 2 problems here
1. How can I send an automatic chat for every possible case from the backend automatically?
2. After I send the message, I want to make sure that all the respond I will get from the user is going to a specific intent that I want.

From what I understand to initiate an intent you have to send a chat/request first then it is not possible to get into intent without it. but I want it to know which intent even before he reply

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you wanted to do here that are not natural, I guess. Let me go on each:

1. How can I send an automatic chat for every possible case from the backend automatically?

Ans: You are building a google assistant on dialog flow, using as a chatbot, any chatbot can not send an automatic message(unless set by user), chatbots, and assistants are in the nature of the user interaction.

Let's any bot on Facebook, Skype, or any platform even the google assistant, they can't popup unwantedly with any information, it will be not user friendly.

There is a way to do, like if the user is interacting with your bot: You can ask like:
'Do you want me to remind you for saving money every day'

If user gives permission, save it in-app local cache and send app notification, via. Once the user get the app notification you can invoke the chat on the app notification click and open chat screen with your reply, but in the background when the user clicks on app notification you have to send a request to initiate chat.

And this solves your second problem as well.

Let me give you a high-level example:

```
Three Intent: With some user utterance 

GetLatestMoive: ['get me the latest moives list']

GetLatestNews: ['Headline for today']

HealthCheck: ['I want health tips']
```

Create Notification and send it to the user via the app:

Based on the notification if the user clicks any of them, initiate your chat in-app with that utterance, it will automatically call the intent, and rest will follow based on your intent follow up a map and conversation design.

Hope this helps!